# AWS Api Gateway custom domain name certificate blocked in pending state (Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, aws-certificate-manager, aws-route53

I try to create an AWS api gateway with a custom domain name and SSL certificate.

I already bought a registered domain `root.com` and have an hosted zone `app.root.com` for my cloudfront frontend. I want then to expose my api gateway to `api.app.root.com`.

I use this terraform code :

`certificate.tf`

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "api" {
  domain_name       = "api.app.root.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = app.root.com
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.api.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "api" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.api.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.api_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

`dns.tf`

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "api" {
  domain_name = aws_acm_certificate.api.domain_name

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.api.arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate_validation.api]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api" {
  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id

  alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name_configuration[0].hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

So my certificate is still in the pending state. I really want to set up my api gateway like this but when I try to configure my certificate on `api.root.com` (so the datasource aws_route53_zone.main is set to `root.com`), my certificate is issued instantly.

I want to know if I can actually achieve what am i trying to do and how ? If it is something that I cannot achieve I am really interested to know why.

Thanks !

Comment: A wild guess: is the provider configuration using the region setting? In other words, are you sure resources are getting deployed in the correct region?

Comment: Your question kind of focuses on API Gateway, but the issue is with the AWS ACM service and Route53. Go into the AWS console, to the ACM service, and look at the pending certificate, and the verification DNS record ACM is telling you to create. Now go here: https://dnschecker.org/all-tools.php and enter that DNS record, and see if it resolves. If it doesn't resolve, then your domain name registrar probably isn't delegating DNS to your Route53 hosted zone.